# Как дождаться окончания нескольких Future?

Tags: dart

Есть асинхронная функция загрузки данных из интернета `loadPage( String url ) async`.

Нужно дождаться загрузки нескольких страниц.
Пишу так (и это плохо):

```dart
void init() async {
  await loadPage( url1 );
  await loadPage( url2 );
  await loadPage( url3 );
}

void main() async {
  await init();
}
```

То есть вместо того, чтобы асинхронно загрузить все страницы, я их загружаю последовательно синхронно и поймал тупняк не понимая, как это исправить.

Comment: Не знaю, как это на Dart, но на C# я бы написал что-то такое: `var task1 = loadPage( url1 ); var task2 = loadPage( url2 ); var task3 = loadPage( url3 ); await task1; await task2; await task3;`. Более идиоматично, конечно, `await Task.WhenAll(loadPage(url1), loadPage(url2), loadPage(url3));`.

Comment: Блин. Точно. В Dart можно также написать. И аналог WhenAll тоже есть :( Называется Future.wait

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сначала создать все объекты `Future`, а потом ждать их выполнения с помощью `await`:

```dart
void init() async {
  var task1 = loadPage( url1 );
  var task2 = loadPage( url2 );
  var task3 = loadPage( url3 );
  await task1;
  await task2;
  await task3;
}
```

### Правильный подход - использовать `Future.wait`

```dart
void init() async {
  return Future.wait(
    [
      loadPage( url1 ),
      loadPage( url2 ),
      loadPage( url3 ),
    ],
  )
}
```